# Redirect wordpress home page by referrer http request

Tags: php, wordpress, referrer

I need to redirect to a static *.html page my wordpress homepage when the http request come from instagram website. I tried to add this code in a custom plugin , but it doesn't work:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_ref');
function redirect_ref () {
    $referer = wp_get_referer();
    if (is_home() && strpos(parse_url(wp_get_referer())['host'],'l.instagram.com'))){
        wp_redirect('/custom_page.html');
}
```

Comment: please explain it more briefly.

Comment: when users open my website from instagram, website should redirect to a static page

Comment: Every time you say “doesn't work” here on this site, it means _you_ have not working. Please go read [ask], and then give us a _proper_ problem description, including what you have done so far to try and debug this.

Comment: "doesn't work" mean that page hasn't been redirect

Comment: I check  $referer = wp_get_referer(); return false.

Answer (score 0):

i think i understood your problem.

The best way is to solve it via a get parameter. 
You can add this to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} inst
RewriteRule ^$ /example.html? [L,R=301]
```

and link your webpage with this link:

`www.yourpage.de?inst`

and it will redirect to `www.yourpage.de/example.html`

Comment: You can also use a plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: I have to redirect users who visit my site by clicking instagram, your solution refers to the queries made on my site